# Nil Cells When Using UISearchDisplayController on UIStoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, searchbar, uistoryboard

I am using UIStoryboard in my iPhone project, and have a controller that is a subclass of UITableViewController and have UISearchDisplayController.

At tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, I am getting the cell using:

```
MyCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

The CellIdentifier is the identifier for my prototype cell. That works ok when displaying the table rows, but once I edit the search bar, and the view trying to display search results I got nil cell.

Answer (score 3):

Add this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

And, if like me, you changed the rowHeight of your table cell rows, you'll need to implement this method too

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.tableView.rowHeight;
}
```